# Ice sliding physics

Tags: 3d, physics, movement

I am trying to implement ice sliding physics on a plane for my game. There are a lot of N64 games that implemented them perfectly well, like Banjo-Kazooie, Super Mario 64, Zelda: OoT and MM, etc.

Here is an example: http://youtu.be/p2D4Y4tMOas?t=19s

Looked up everywhere and I can't find a guide for it. Anyone knows how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Ice is just a low-friction surface.  You'll probably have more luck googling for information about implementing friction in game physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very simple version is reducing the velocity of the player by a set amount (when he isn't holding down any controls) on normal terrain, and reducing it *less* on ice.

You can also go for the physics approach, which is more complicated, but will result in more realistic results.

**Crash Course - Physics**

The player has a mass. Ice (and other surfaces) has a friction coefficient. Multiply the coefficient by the mass of the player to get a scalar force. Apply the force in the opposite direction of the player's motion.

Force = Mass * Acceleration. Divide force by mass to get the acceleration of the player. Multiply acceleration by time (seconds) to get change in velocity.

Comment: Another way to think of this is that, when on a surface, the player's velocity is adjusted by a varying amount to match the velocity of that surface. Thinking about it this way, it works for moving platforms too. Stationary ground is just a special case where the velocity of the surface is zero.